# Defining a Keras function

Tags: function, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have recently started to learn Deep Learning and CNNs. I have come across the following code which defines a simple CNN.

Can anyone help me to understand how these lines work:

1. `loss = layer_output[:, :, :, 0]` - What is the result of this ? My question is that, the network has not been trained yet. Weights [Kernels] are not yet calculated. so, what data it is going to return !! Does `0` represent the first kernel ?
2. `iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])` - There is not much documentation available on Keras site. What I understand is that `iterate` is a function which takes an Input tensor and returns a list of tensors, first one is `loss` and second one is `grads`. But, they are defined elsewhere !!

Define Input Image with these dimensions:

```py
img_data = np.random.uniform(size=(1, 250, 250, 3))
```

There is a Simple CNN, which has one Convolutional layer. It uses two 3 X 3 kernels.

```py
input = Input(shape=250, 250, 3,), name='input_1')

First_Conv2D = Conv2D(2, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding="same", name='conv2d_1', activation='relu')(input)
flat = Flatten(name='flatten_1')(First_Conv2D)
output = Dense(2, name='dense_1', activation='softmax')(flat)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])

layer_dict = dict([(layer.name, layer) for layer in model.layers[0:]])
layer_output = layer_dict['conv2d_1'].output

input_img = model.input

# Calculate loss and gradient.
loss = layer_output[:, :, :, 0]
grads = K.gradients(loss, input_img)[0]

# Define a Keras function
iterate = K.function([input_img], [loss, grads])

# Call iterate function 
loss_value, grads_value = iterate([img_data])
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nasty dissection of Keras as an API. I reckon it leads to more confusion rather than an introduction to deep learning. Anyway, addressing your questions:

1. All tensors are *symbolic* meaning that until we run a session, they do not contain any values. They instead define a directed computation graph. The `loss = layer_output[:,:,:,0]` is an slicing operation that takes the first element of the last dimension returning another tensor with 3 dimensions. When you run the session with actual inputs, then the tensors will have values which these operations run. The operations are almost identical to NumPy ndarrays which are not symbolic and contain values, you can get an intuition.
2. [K.function](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/794f814343b655e01de73578d71e8b8a53523687/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2670) just glues the inputs to the outputs returning a single operation that when given the inputs it will follow the computation graph from the inputs to the defined outputs. In this case, given a list of single input it returns a list of 2 output tensors loss and gradients. These are still symbolic remember, if you try to print one you'll just get what it is and it's shape, data type.

Comment: Thank you nuric for your answer.  How can the same logic be implemented without using K.function in this case ?